# static() helper function django

Tags: django

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Dears, where can I learn more about how this static() function process the two arguments passed?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve

Comment: have you got the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve


def static(prefix, view=serve, **kwargs):
    """
    Return a URL pattern for serving files in debug mode.

    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns = [
        # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    """
    if not prefix:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("Empty static prefix not permitted")
    elif not settings.DEBUG or urlsplit(prefix).netloc:
        # No-op if not in debug mode or a non-local prefix.
        return []
    return [
        re_path(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % re.escape(prefix.lstrip('/')), view, kwargs=kwargs),
    ]
```

I found out the best way to understand this function is to read its source code!